# jQuery .html only get last value of JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a problem with `jQuery("#someID").html`. It only prints the last key from the JSON.

Here is the js:

```
<div class="row" id="fetchmember">
  <script type="text/javascript">

jQuery('#group').change(function() {
    var id_group = this.value; 
    var memberjson = "fetchmember.php?group="+id_group;

    jQuery.getJSON(memberjson, function(data) {
        jQuery.each(data, function(i, items) {
            jQuery("#fetchmember").html("<li>"+items.name+"</li>");
        });                 
    });
});

  </script>
</div>
```

JSON result from one of the selected option :

```
[{"id":"1645819602","name":"Michael English","first_name":"Michael","last_name":"English"},
{"id":"100000251643877","name":"Bill Gaither","first_name":"Bill","last_name":"Gaither"}]
```

I want to print all of `name` from the json, but it print only last `name` key of the json. What's wrong with my code?

Any advice and helps would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're erasing the content on each iteration. Use `append` instead of `html`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
jQuery("#fetchmember").html("<li>"+items.name+"</li>");
```

Use

```
jQuery("#fetchmember").append("<li>"+items.name+"</li>");
```

At iteration, you overwrite the content with last one.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use `.append` instead of `.html`, but you have to make the area empty before : `jQuery("#fetchmember").empty();`